# Using shared_ptr without name?!

Tags: c++

I'm reading the book "Game Coding Complete" which basically is about the concept of game engines.
The part about resource cache has some code I don't quite understand.

```
extern shared_ptr<IResourceLoader> CreateWAVResourceLoader();
```

where CreateWAVResourceLoader() looks like

```
    shared_ptr<IResourceLoader> CreateWAVResourceLoader()
{
    return shared_ptr<IResourceLoader>(GCC_NEW WaveResourceLoader());
}
```

and afterwards the authors register the wave resource loader

```
m_ResCache->RegisterLoader(CreateWAVResourceLoader());
```

To me, the line `extern shared_ptr<IResourceLoader> CreateWAVResourceLoader();` is a little bit confusing, because I'm calling the function which returns a shared_ptr, but how can I use that pointer without a name? I'm pretty sure it's my lack of experience in C++, so please enlighten me. :)

Thanks!

Comment: `extern` keyword has no effect on function declarations, is that what is confusing you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line *is* a function declaration. It is named `CreateWAVResourceLoader`, has no parameters, and returns a `shared_ptr<IResourceLoader>`.

When you say:

```
m_ResCache->RegisterLoader(CreateWAVResourceLoader());
```

That's when you call it. It passes the temporary shared pointer returned from the function into `RegisterLoader`.

Answer (score 2):

> but how can I use that pointer without a name?

You're not the one who will be using the shared_ptr, the object `m_ResCache` will be. I assume that object has an interface for handling resources, and keeps track of shared_ptrs internally.

i.e. it's like this:

```
class foo {
  public:
    RegisterLoader(shared_ptr<IResourceLoader> ptr) { internal_ptr = ptr; }

    DoSomethingWithLoader() { /* ... */ }
  private:
    shared_ptr<IResourceLoader> internal_ptr;
};
```

Comment: +1, but did you really just refrain from using a member initalizer?

Answer (score 0):

```
extern shared_ptr<IResourceLoader> CreateWAVResourceLoader();
```

just means that the function will be implemented in another file (extern) and that it will return shared_ptr. The whole line is just a function declaration and

```
shared_ptr<IResourceLoader> CreateWAVResourceLoader()
{
    return shared_ptr<IResourceLoader>(GCC_NEW WaveResourceLoader());
}
```

is just an implementation of the function.

Comment: What you call definition is more commonly and accurately called *declaration*. To make the potential for confusion worse, *definition* is the official term for the implementation.